# За город-таки / за город таки

Tags: дефис

Как мы знаем, мы пишет частицу *-таки* через дефис, если – это один случай, если что, – она вместе с наречием используется. У меня возникает вопрос: а если это наречие выражено через существительное, то мы, используя *-таки*, через дефис пишем эту частицу с этим существительным или без него?

Ответьте, нужен ли дефис в следующих предложениях, пожалуйста.

1. Мы поехали за город-таки.
2. Иногда мы через дефис-таки пишем частицу *-таки*, а иногда – без.
3. За границей-таки хорошо.
4. Мы брали котят по одному-таки. (Здесь вообще числительное.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что во всех примерах дефис писать **не нужно**.

Дело в том, что ***за город, за границей, по одному*** – это не наречия, а обстоятельственные **существительные** с предложным управлением. Иногда их могут называть наречными выражениями.

В предложениях они могут быть различными **обстоятельствами** (где, куда, как).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: нет. Частица **ТАКИ** пишется через дефис только с глаголами, наречиями и другими частицами: *Много-таки* (наречие), *всë-таки* (частица), *сделать-таки* (глагол).

С остальными частями речи частица ТАКИ пишется **раздельно**.

Так что правильно:

***Мы поехали за город таки***;

***Иногда мы через дефис таки пишем частицу -таки, а иногда — без***;

***За границей таки хорошо***;

***Мы брали котят по одному таки***.

Comment: Сэр, кстати, считаете ли вы тоже, что, если *-таки* – это в предложении подлежащие, не стоит ставить дефис? Я считаю, что так правильно, так как, так делая, автор даёт возможность дать понять тому, кто читает, что это не выражение *всё-таки*, а это *всё* как подлежащие с частицой *-таки*. Пример обычный: *Он всё-таки хороший кот – этот Мететех.* То, про что я говорю: ***Всё таки** у него было хорошо, даже когда кризис пришёл, так как он деньгу-то скопил-подкопил.* (Здесь *Всё* – это подлежащие, а *таки* вообще можно убрать-таки.)

Comment: Всë правильно, *таки* пишется раздельно. Потому что __ВСË__ не частица и не наречие, а либо местоим. числительное, либо местоим. сущ. Я больше склоняюсь к тому, что это всë-таки местоименное существительное. Так что Вы правы, верно раздельное написание.